# My client is unable to read the message from the firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

These are my firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "intents" : {
      ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
      ".write" : true
    },
    "messages" : {
      "$user" : {
           ".read":  "auth.uid === data.child('to').val() || 
                      auth.uid === data.child('from').val() ||
                     (auth.uid === 'iAmEd' && data.child('to').val() === 'Ed') || 
                      data.child('to').val() === 'all'",
           ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The explanation for read operation on `messages` is:

1. If a message is sent to the user A, A is allowed to read it (`auth.uid === data.child('to').val()`)
2. If a message is sent by a user A, A is allowed to read it (`auth.uid === data.child('from').val()`)
3. server can read all the messages (i.e. `uid = "iAmEd"`), also the message must have "Ed" in the `to` section. (`(auth.uid === 'iAmEd' && data.child('to').val() === 'Ed')`)
4. If a message is sent as `to` = "all", the message can be read by everyone.

Although the write operation is working fine. But my client is unable to read any message, neither sent by it, nor the message with `to` set to `all`.

Below are two sample messages for reference:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
      "from" : "Ed",
      "name" : "Ed",
      "photoUrl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png",
      "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed",
      "timeStamp" : "1476880306",
      "to" : "all",
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-KWK50chFl_QroPwoYVu" : {
      "from" : "Capyv3mxQsUUn2W1nPOgcJ0Ex9T2",
      "name" : "Aakash Bansal",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-oQyA4HXVycc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHKo/Ov0A0p0LjiY/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "text" : "hi",
      "timeStamp" : "1478896392",
      "to" : "Ed",
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}
```

I viewed several youtube videos too, but their is no reference for as to how to compare strings in firebase security rules.

**EDIT**: When I used thses simple rules, they didn't work too. Although the user is able to write but it is not reading any messages.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "intents" : {
      ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
      ".write" : true
    },
    "messages" : {
      "$message" : {
           ".read" : "data.child('from').val() === auth.uid"
      },
          ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if you think that their might be some problem in my Android code or RecyclerAdapter implementation, I may tell that when I used `".read" : true`, the android was able to read the code properly.

Hence, their is definitely some problem with my rules only.

**EDIT 2** One more problem, when I used the following rules, the app is still not reading the data.

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
    "$message" : {
           ".read":  true,
    },
        ".write": true
  }
}
}
```

But when I use the following code, the app reads data accurately:

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
        ".read":  true,
        ".write": true
  }
}
}
```

Following is the android code that reads the data:

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Context context;

    public MessageAdapter(Class<FriendlyMessage> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<MessageViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref, Context context, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
        this.context = context;
        this.mProgressBar =progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateViewHolder reached");
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.getMessageTextView().setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
        viewHolder.getMessengerTextView().setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
        if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
            viewHolder.getMessengerImageView()
                    .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat
                            .getDrawable(context,
                                    tod));
        } else {
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(viewHolder.getMessengerImageView());
        }
        boolean temp;
        try {
            temp = friendlyMessage.getName().equals("Ed");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            temp = false;
        }
        if (temp) {
            viewHolder.getDiffForRecSend().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);
            viewHolder.getMessageTextView().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));
            viewHolder.getMessengerTextView().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getDiffForRecSend().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blankbluebububble);
            viewHolder.getMessengerTextView().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue1));
            viewHolder.getMessageTextView().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "populateViewHolder ended");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  /***/
  mFirebaseAdapter = new MessageAdapter(FriendlyMessage.class,
              R.layout.item_message,
              MessageViewHolder.class,
              mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("/messages"),
              context,
              mProgressBar);
  /***/
```

I have simply used FirebaseUI and a custom Recycler Adapter that extends it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you say you can't read data, show the code that tries to read data and that fails. Typically this should also show an error message in the logcat. If it does, include that in your question too.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, I am really not able to figure out why these rules are not working. I checked out the answers at Google Groups but no help!